# Angular dynamic array showing all results not just data under id

Tags: arrays, angular, dynamic, angular-activatedroute

I am still trying to learn what seems to me like advanced Angular 5. The below code does enter the "id" number from the array into the url as expected, but when I go to model/1 it shows my all the objects from the array. I need to only see the object under id 1 and same for each object in the array. I have found so much conflicting information online, from mapping to queries that I'm not even sure where to being and everything I've tried has led to no better results. I have included all the code I'm working with.

I have an array of objects in my json file-

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Metal Man",
    "sample": "/assets/img/metalman1.png",
    "fab": "https://sketchfab.com/models/1b3cb7f8a77145bc8616075e9036b025/embed",
    "img1": "/assets/img/metalman1.png",
    "img2": "/assets/img/metalman2.png",
    "img3": "/assets/img/metalman3.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Magrot",
    "sample": "/assets/img/magrot1.png",
    "fab": "https://sketchfab.com/models/e20c8ade2f16452ca7f440aa84fc8e33/embed",
    "img1": "/assets/img/magrot1.png",
    "img2": "/assets/img/magrot2.png",
    "img3": "/assets/img/magrot3.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "Baseball and Bat",
    "sample": "/assets/img/ball1.png",
    "fab": "https://sketchfab.com/models/781c60d3449b46f996a081ae36c20cce/embed",
    "img1": "/assets/img/ball1.png",
    "img2": "/assets/img/ball2.png",
    "img3": "/assets/img/ball3.png"
  }
]
```

My template for each of the above objects-

```
<div class="columnFlex mainBlock" *ngFor="let model of modelwork">
<div class="modelImagery">
  <h1>{{ model.label }}</h1>
  <iframe [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(model.fab)'
    frameborder="1" allowvr allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen="true"
    webkitallowfullscreen="true" onmousewheel=""></iframe>
    <img [src]="model.img1" />
    <img [src]="model.img2" />
    <img [src]="model.img3" />
  </div></div>
```

And my Activatedroute set up-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-model',
  templateUrl: './model.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./model.component.css']
})
export class ModelComponent implements OnInit {

  modelwork: any;

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {this.modelwork = params['id'];});
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
       this.http.get<any>('./assets/models.json').subscribe(
         data => {
           this.modelwork = data;
         })
  }

}
```

Any clarification on what I'm needing to do would be so appreciated! I'm trying to learn Angular in days and it is more complicated than I had expected. Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: What exact issue you are facing in this. can you please let us know

Comment: I'm trying to only show this data per page-
`"id": 1,

    "label": "Metal Man",
    "sample": "/assets/img/metalman1.png",
    "fab": "https://sketchfab.com/models/1b3cb7f8a77145bc8616075e9036b025/embed",
    "img1": "/assets/img/metalman1.png",
    "img2": "/assets/img/metalman2.png",
    "img3": "/assets/img/metalman3.png"`

right now it is showing all 3 sections of code in the same page. So if I go to website.com/model/1 I only need to see the info under id 1

Comment: ok make sense but how you will identify which key should be shown on page one and which need to be shown on page 2, any relation in page number and data

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything advanced here. You simple have two asynchronous operations that both set the variable 'modelwork'. One of the operations sets modelwork to an integer and the other sets it to a json array. depending on which operation resolves first.

**Edit**

Looking at your comment, i see what you want to do. Here's an example:

```
chosenIndex: any;
modelwork: any;

constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, public sanitizer: DomSanitizer ) {
  this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.chosenIndex = params['id'];

    this.http.get<any>('./assets/models.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.modelwork = data.filter(d => d['id'] == this.chosenIndex);
    })
  });
}
```

Modelwork will now contain an array of 1 object. The one object you want. You can alter this example to get whatever output you want.

Comment: I feel like I was way off track on this. I didn't realize I could have the route.params in the ngOnInit. All the examples I've seen have it under constructor and that really threw me off. It felt a whole lot more complicated than it is seeing it now. You obviously understand Angular and Typescript well, was there a class, book, or tutorial that you followed to learn this? I've been thrown into this and I'm trying to ramp up beyond fast. Thank you again for taking the time to look at this and for helping me out.

Comment: No problem. Work just gave me some time to calmly learn Angular which made it a much more enjoyable experience. No classes or books, just test projects and time.

Comment: That's awesome, I have a couple of more days to have some of this figured out and I'm the only front-end dev working a massive project. Thank you again so much for the help :)

Comment: I have stackoverflow open all day if you need a quick answer for anything.

Comment: I finished my project, but for some reason when I built and deployed the dist contents to my Plesk server on GoDaddy I'm not getting the JSON at all. The Chrome tools show a 404 for finding the JSON, but it works perfectly locally. Am I missing something important to get the server to find the JSON? Even if I just put the files into the URL it can't locate the files at all.

Comment: Where is the JSON file located?